# Is it possible to use pure CSS to resize a div's width based on contained image width, but not when browser window resizes?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm making a tumblr theme and I'm creating a `div` around each rendered post. I have, for my index page, the images of photo posts set to have a width of `400px`, using the markup

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-400}" width="400" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
```

This looks fine with photo posts, but sometimes text posts get several series of `blockquote`s, and those can contain images which will unfortunately expand outside of the box.

[image: contained image doesn't fit]

**Some clarification**: on tumblr, a "photo post" is an image with an HTML caption, while a text post is basically just some HTML. The image outside of this HTML caption is constrained to the size I set in my template markup, but the images inside the HTML caption (and in text posts in general) are not.

The behavior I am seeking is that these `div`s will always be `400px` wide, with 10px padding on all sides, unless contained content overflows outside of the container, in which case the width will adjust to fit that content. But, changing the size of the browser window should not affect the size of the `div`s. The image inside the HTML caption should never resize; it is a separate case from a photo post's image.

Here's how the markup looks:

```
<div class="post-box">
  <article class="post">
    <p>...</p>
    <blockquote>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>
          <img src="..." />
      </p>
    </blockquote>
    <p>...</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

My CSS thus far is as such:

```
.post-box {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: {color:Postbox Color};
  {block:IndexPage}
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 0%;
    max-width: 800px;
  {/block:IndexPage}
}
.post-box img {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS?

*Edit:* this diagram may help clarify my needs. Here is a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/B35AW/1/

[image: box should expand to fit content, plus 10px padding, but should not expand past 800px wide]

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the final state you want the post-box div, the block-quote and the image to be in?  Its coming across like you want the layout and the written content to be responsive but you don't want the images to resize under 400px?

Comment: @Lowkase The template for photo posts makes it so that the photos are `400px` wide, but the template for the text posts lets the images have their original width. Those latter kinds of images shouldn't resize. The `div` should be a minimum of `400px` wide, but should be wider if there are such kinds of images inside it which are too big to fit into that box, either by virtue of their sizes alone or because of indentation from the `blockquote`s or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a pure CSS solution for this, but I did write some JavaScript which took care of my solution (using jQuery):

```
function boxExpandForContents() {
  $.each($('.post-box'), function(i, box){
    var width = 0, $box = $(box);
    var padding = parseInt($box.css('padding-left')) + parseInt($box.css('padding-right'));
    $.each($box.find('p img'), function(j, img){
      width = (img.x + img.width > width) ? img.x + img.width : width;
      if (width > 800) {
        width = 800;
        $(img).width(width - img.x);
      }
    });
    width = width - padding;
    width = (width > 500) ? width : 500;
    $box.width(width);
    $box.find('.post-info').width(width);
  })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  boxExpandForContents();
});
```

Using `$box.find('p img')` let me grab any images what were in the HTML rendered by the `{Caption}` token. This was the best I could do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    .post-box img {
      display: block;
      line-height: 0;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto
    }

edit: i just changed max-width to width and removed height and it's working as you can see in the screenshot 
[image: screen shoot of the result]

Comment: This did seemingly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stuff that fulfills your box needs:

```
.post-box {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 400px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  float:left;
}
.post img {
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  width:400px;
}

.post {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It will automatically expand to `800px`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B35AW/

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with the issues you were still seeing. However, until you make some css for the blockquote you used in the jsfiddle it will be wider than 400px because blockquotes have default margins and padding.

Comment: It still automatically expands to `800px` if the contents overflow at all. I added CSS for the `blockquote`s but it made no difference. I also didn't want/need the `float: left;`, and didn't want `img`s inside the `article.post` to be resized to `400px` wide, but I do appreciate the help so far.

Comment: well, this solution does not work without the float. You need it to make the rest of it work, and you did say at the very top of your question you have all pics at 400px. Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: delete `float` and replace `display:block` with `display:inline-block` and it will work also. I checked it in your fiddle and it works great.

Comment: Doing that had a similar (but neater) effect. If two posts can fit in the window space horizontally in line with each other, they will. For some reason, wrt width, this fiddle isn't showing what's happening on my page anyway!

I'm sorry for the confusion, but I'm not sure how to be more clear. A photo post is composed of a photo (which is rendered via the template markup at the top of my post) and an HTML caption (which is rendered as-is with the `{Caption}` token). The images causing my woes are in the latter.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the `blockquote` CSS? I tried setting a `max-width` on it to no effect.

Comment: Or rather, it did have an effect on the element, but the box didn't resize at all.